# PowerShell richtextbox change colour of new line

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

Nice and simple question, but a minefield of c# responses on Google that make sense to a PowerShell person like me (I need to learn!)

I have a richtextbox created using XAML, and I'd like to have the ability to add a line in a different coloured font.

Most of the Saipen results suggest $formLogReport.SelectionColor but no such property exists.

I've actually found something that does work but it's overkill and goes beyond what I know about PowerShell - I'm reluctant to use code I don't understand.

http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powercli/powershell-gui-format-text-on-textbox-and-richtextbox

For reference, the code below uses the function from the link provided.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'presentationframework' )
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )


[xml]$xaml =  @'
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="RichTextBox Example" Height="530" Width="740" >

<Grid Name="GridName">

    <Label Name="SetupLabel" Content="Setup type" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="30,25,30,30" Height="25" Width="320" />
    <ComboBox Name="SetupList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="30,55,30,30" Height="25" Width="320" />

    <Label Name="SubsiteLabel" Content="Text in here will be a different size" FontSize="11" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,265,30,30" Height="25" Width="320" />
    <TextBox Name="SubsiteBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,295,0,0" 
        Height="25" Width="320" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

    <Label Name="StuffLabelLabel" Content="Enter Stuff to show up" FontSize="11" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,345,30,30" Height="25" Width="320" />
    <TextBox Name="StuffBox" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Margin="30,375,0,0" Height="25" Width="320" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

    <Label Name="LogLabel" Content="Log..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11"
        Margin="390,25,0,0" Height="25" Width="320"  />

    <RichTextBox Name="LogReport" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="390,55,0,0" 
        Height="345" Width="300"  >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>"HI THERE"
                <Run Text=""/>
            </Paragraph>  
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>

    <Button Name="GoButton" Content="Go!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="625,435,0,0"
        Height="25" Width="65" IsEnabled="False" />


</Grid>
</Window>
'@


$reader = ( New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml )

try {
$Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

}
catch {
Write-Warning "Unable to parse XML, with error: $( $Error[0] )`n "
}


#===========================================================================
# Load XAML Objects / Form Changes & Conditions
#===========================================================================


$xaml.SelectNodes( "//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name "form$( $_.Name )" -Value $Form.FindName( $_.Name ) }



function Format-RichTextBox {  
#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement(v=vs.110).aspx#Propertiesshut  
param (  
  [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]  
  [System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox]$RichTextBoxControl,  
  [String]$Text,  
  [String]$ForeGroundColor = 'Black',  
  [String]$BackGroundColor = 'White',  
  [String]$FontSize = '12',  
  [String]$FontStyle = 'Normal',  
  [String]$FontWeight = 'Normal',  
  [Switch]$NewLine  
)

$ParamOptions = $PSBoundParameters  
$RichTextRange = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange( $RichTextBoxControl.Document.ContentEnd, $RichTextBoxControl.Document.ContentEnd )  
if ($ParamOptions.ContainsKey('NewLine')) {  
  $RichTextRange.Text = "`n$Text"  
}  
else {  
  $RichTextRange.Text = $Text  
}  

$Defaults = @{ForeGroundColor='Black';BackGroundColor='White';FontSize='12'; FontStyle='Normal'; FontWeight='Normal'}  
foreach ($Key in $Defaults.Keys) {  
  if ($ParamOptions.Keys -notcontains $Key) {  
    $ParamOptions.Add($Key, $Defaults[$Key])  
  }  
}   

$AllParameters = $ParamOptions.Keys | Where-Object {@('RichTextBoxControl','Text','NewLine') -notcontains $_}  
foreach ($SelectedParam in $AllParameters) {  
  if ($SelectedParam -eq 'ForeGroundColor') {$TextElement = [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::ForegroundProperty}  
  elseif ($SelectedParam -eq 'BackGroundColor') {$TextElement = [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::BackgroundProperty}  
  elseif ($SelectedParam -eq 'FontSize') {$TextElement = [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::FontSizeProperty}  
  elseif ($SelectedParam -eq 'FontStyle') {$TextElement = [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::FontStyleProperty}  
  elseif ($SelectedParam -eq 'FontWeight') {$TextElement = [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::FontWeightProperty}  
  $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue($TextElement, $ParamOptions[$SelectedParam])  
}  
  }




$formstuffbox.Add_KeyDown( {
If ( $args[1].key -eq 'Return' ) {
    $formLogReport.AppendText( "$( $formstuffbox.text )`n" )
}
} ) 


$formsubsitebox.Add_KeyDown( {
If ( $args[1].key -eq 'Return' ) {
    Format-RichTextBox -RichTextBoxControl $formLogReport -Text $formsubsitebox.text -ForeGroundColor Red
}
} ) 


$form.ShowDialog()
```

Does anyone know of a simpler method? It's only ever going to be used for errors, so only ever needs to become red.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so having spent the best part of 8 hours looking for an easy solution, I decided to churn away at the function already in place and try to dissect what it was doing.
The author Kunal Udapi – to whom I’m very grateful for – has accounted for all possible font changes, for what I want it’s far too much and unnecessary.

To anyone else who came her via a Google result, check out the original code via Github here: https://github.com/kunaludapi/Powershell/blob/master/Powershell%20GUI%20format%20text/Format-TextBlock.ps1

Alternatively my example simplifies it dramatically for just changing colour and can be easily modified for font changes.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'presentationframework' )
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )

[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
Title="RichTextBox Example" Height="530" Width="740" >

<Grid Name="GridName">

    <RichTextBox Name="richtextbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="66,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="643">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="Good morning"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Foreground="#FFD30F0F" FontSize="14" Text="Hi there, how's it going?"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <TextBox Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="68,313,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540"/>
    <Button Name="gobutton1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="634,313,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
'@


$reader = ( New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml )

try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Unable to parse XML, with error: $( $Error[0] )`n "
}

#===========================================================================
# Load XAML Objects / Form Changes & Conditions
#===========================================================================


$xaml.SelectNodes( "//*[@Name]" ) | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name "form$( $_.Name )" -Value $Form.FindName( $_.Name ) }

Function WriteRichTextBox {
    Param(
        [string]$text,
        [string]$colour = "Black"
    )

    $RichTextRange = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange( 
        $formrichtextbox1.Document.ContentEnd,$formrichtextbox1.Document.ContentEnd ) 
    $RichTextRange.Text = $text
    $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue( ( [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::ForegroundProperty ), $colour )  

}

$formtextbox1.Add_KeyDown( {
    If ( $args[1].key -eq 'Return' ) {
        WriteRichTextBox -text "`n$( $formtextbox1.text )" -Colour "Green"
    }
} )

$formgobutton1.Add_Click( {
    WriteRichTextBox -text "`n$( $formtextbox1.text )"
} )

$form.ShowDialog()
```